# using PyPlot crash Julia

Tags: python, matplotlib, julia, jupyter-notebook

I just did a fresh install of `Julia 0.5.2` and `Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.` through Anaconda. When `using PyPlot` in a jupyter notebook (with julia kernel), I get the following:

```
InitError: PyError (:PyImport_ImportModule

The Python package matplotlib.pyplot could not be found by pyimport. Usually this means
that you did not install matplotlib.pyplot in the Python version being used by PyCall.

PyCall is currently configured to use the Python version at:

/home/riccardo/anaconda3/bin/python

and you should use whatever mechanism you usually use (apt-get, pip, conda,
etcetera) to install the Python package containing the matplotlib.pyplot module.

One alternative is to re-configure PyCall to use a different Python
version on your system: set ENV["PYTHON"] to the path/name of the python
executable you want to use, run Pkg.build("PyCall"), and re-launch Julia.

Another alternative is to configure PyCall to use a Julia-specific Python
distribution via the Conda.jl package (which installs a private Anaconda
Python distribution), which has the advantage that packages can be installed
and kept up-to-date via Julia.  As explained in the PyCall documentation,
set ENV["PYTHON"]="", run Pkg.build("PyCall"), and re-launch Julia. Then,
To install the matplotlib.pyplot module, you can use `pyimport_conda("matplotlib.pyplot", PKG)`,
where PKG is the Anaconda package the contains the module matplotlib.pyplot,
or alternatively you can use the Conda package directly (via
`using Conda` followed by `Conda.add` etcetera).

) <class 'ImportError'>
ImportError("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /home/riccardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/../../.././libpng16.so.16)",)
  File "/home/riccardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 29, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/home/riccardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 36, in <module>
    import matplotlib.contour as contour
  File "/home/riccardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/contour.py", line 21, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
  File "/home/riccardo/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 58, in <module>
    from matplotlib import afm, cbook, ft2font, rcParams, get_cachedir

during initialization of module PyPlot

 in pyerr_check at /home/riccardo/.julia/v0.5/PyCall/src/exception.jl:56 [inlined]
 in pyerr_check at /home/riccardo/.julia/v0.5/PyCall/src/exception.jl:61 [inlined]
 in macro expansion at /home/riccardo/.julia/v0.5/PyCall/src/exception.jl:81 [inlined]
 in pyimport(::String) at /home/riccardo/.julia/v0.5/PyCall/src/PyCall.jl:374
 in __init__() at /home/riccardo/.julia/v0.5/PyPlot/src/init.jl:184
 in _include_from_serialized(::String) at ./loading.jl:150
 in _require_from_serialized(::Int64, ::Symbol, ::String, ::Bool) at ./loading.jl:187
 in _require_search_from_serialized(::Int64, ::Symbol, ::String, ::Bool) at ./loading.jl:217
 in require(::Symbol) at ./loading.jl:371
 in include_string(::String, ::String) at ./loading.jl:441
```

However, I checked using `anaconda-navigator` and the `matplotlib` is present (in a jupyter notebook with a python kernel `from matplotlib import pyplot` works fine).

Do you have any suggestion on how to fix these? I saw this has been pointed out by other people, but in those cases it seems to be related to the use of multiple environments. While in my case I have only one.

Comment: on my ubuntu 16.04 `ls -la  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1` return  `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.8` which doesnt satisfy version 'ZLIB_1.2.9' but `ls -la anaconda3/lib/libz.so.1` return `anaconda3/lib/libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11` so I propose to try activate anaconda's virtualenv before running julia (or change LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

Comment: I had exactly the same output on my Ubuntu 16.04. Upon activating the `root` environment in anaconda I checked both julia and python versions: those were correct. But instead `using Pyplot` failed again with the same error as before. I then decided to `Pkg.build("PyPlot")` and now `using PyPlot` seems to work, except that it is using the wrong python version `INFO: PyCall is using /home/riccardo/.julia/v0.5/Conda/deps/usr/bin/python (Python 2.7.13) at /home/riccardo/.julia/v0.5/Conda/deps/usr/bin/python, libpython = /home/riccardo/.julia/v0.5/Conda/deps/usr/lib/libpython2.7`

Comment: if you do `using Conda;Conda.list()` do you see matplotlib in list?

Comment: So running `/home/riccardo/anaconda3/bin/python` from the terminal and then `from matplotlib import pyplot` works?

Comment: @Liso Yes, matplotlib is in the list.

Comment: @AlexanderMorley Yes, it works.

Comment: `ldd ~/anaconda3/lib/libpng16.so | grep libz` -> this has to return something different than `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1` . `ls -la /home/palo/anaconda3/lib/libz.so*` could be interesting too. `find / -name "libz.so*" 2>/dev/null` I am curious if there is somewhere libz.so.1.2.9 . I would also try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/riccardo/anaconda3/lib:$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before running julia.

Comment: The first one seems to be exactly where it is supposed to be. `libz.so.1 => /home/riccardo/anaconda3/lib/./libz.so.1 (0x00007ff7c0add000)`. The second one has three different results ` libz.so.1 => /home/riccardo/anaconda3/lib/./libz.so.1 (0x00007f548242f000)
`

Comment: There's no libz.so.1.2.9 anywhere (the output is too long). Your last suggestion,@Liso , in fact works. But, I usually have jupyter notebook with julia kernels, and I'd like to add that `export...` command once and for all somewhere.

Comment: Add it to .bashrc. You could do it by command -> `julia -e 'println("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/riccardo/anaconda3/lib:$(ENV["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"])")' >> ~/.bashrc` . You could then edit last line in `~/.bashrc` to not have `/home/riccardo/anaconda3/lib` two times there. (processes started before this change could reload this settings automatically) (maybe create backup copy of ~/.bashrc for safety! :) )